# MOSFET in h-bridge get hot on idle load

Tags: arduino, mosfet, h-bridge, push-pull

I'm trying to build cheap H-bridge driver to operate under 12-24 input voltage. I used 12 V regulator as separated Vgs voltage driver, also to increase load current and I paralleled two MOSFET with each other and separate gate signal, so it is consist 4 P & 4 N MOSFET type.
I used NAND Schmitt triggers circuit with Enable, Direction and PWM control as per following image, but when I fabricated the board and connected to 12 V power supply and 12 V DC motor, under low PWM frequency (450 Hz) which is made by Arduino uno and no load on motor shaft, it's got unexpectedly **so HOT**.
My NAND Schmitt triggers circuit seems has no design problem and I thought pull-push gate drive circuit for P-MOS with enhanced switching speed. I don't know where should I look for this problem.
Following is the MOSFET data

- SSD20P03  P-MOSFET: 24A, -30V, RDS(ON) 59mΩ
- VGS  20
- Total Gate Charge             6.4nc
- Gate-Source Charge            1.9nc
- Gate-Drain Charge             2.5nc
- Input Capacitance             520pf
- Output Capacitance             13pf
- Reverse Transfer Capacitance   70pf
- Turn-on Delay Time             10ns
- Rise Time                     2.8ns
- Turn-off Delay Time            53ns
- Fall Time                      46ns

---

- SUB45N03  N-MOSFET: 45A, 30V, RDS(ON) 13mΩ
- VGS  20
- Total Gate Charge             40nc
- Gate-Source Charge            7.5nc
- Gate-Drain Charge             8nc
- Input Capacitance             2000pf
- Output Capacitance             370pf
- Reverse Transfer Capacitance   180pf
- Turn-on Delay Time             11-20ns
- Rise Time                     9-20ns
- Turn-off Delay Time            38-70ns
- Fall Time                      11-20ns

---

[image]

Comment: Measure some waveforms

Comment: because your pfets' gates are being pulled to 12v but they're referenced to 24v?

Comment: @PlasmaHH unfortunately I don't have any lab tools or knowledge to test my board, I'm just Arduino enthusiastic with no electrical engineering background

Comment: @Taniwha can you be more specific ? caz I though isolated 12V would be enough to turn on the most of any mosfet

Comment: pfets are turned on when the voltage on their gate is less than the voltage on their drain - they're off when they are about the same - in your case the transistors driving the high side don't go above 12v so the pfets will always be on

Comment: maybe the way to think of it is that is that the problem is not turning the pFets on (they're both always on), it's turning them off, to do that you have to pull their gates to 24v

Comment: There is something strange about your schematic. It's missing connection dots in a lot of places. For example, are you sure that there is a connection between the +24V and the PFET drains?

Comment: Sorry to be the one to inform you, but your success rate at debugging this without an oscilloscope is very low. And what @dim said, no connection dots so your schematic is guesswork. What is 450 f? 450 Hz?

Comment: @dim I upload my schematic at following [link](https://github.com/mkeyno/H-bridge2)

Comment: @winny I edit my question for clearance and upload schematic file for reference

Comment: @Hamid you should update your original post instead of providing the updated schematic through a link.

Comment: @Hamidsk  You must learn how full bridges work best. You have many conceptual design flaws.  YOU have too much to learn.  Level shifters, dead-time control, or PWM sink to Source gate boost charge pump using all N-type.  When you comprehend , define all the specs 1st before designing.  e.g. rise time vs reactive load, dead-time control, efficiency etc

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist I know base principal of h-bridge driver and some preliminary MOSFET calculation before made my PCB, also this schematic is based on some general schematic reference, I think I must  did some mistake on choosing right component for P-MOS driver

Comment: If you design, you need much more than a "basic" principal, have you tested my answer yet? This is a bandaid, and no guarantee on power up, if Vgs(Pch) is overstressed)

Comment: Please update the picture in your post instead of posting a link.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I want to give you a few points I see directly on your design to be problematic:

1. Generation of Forward and Backward signals is off. There is some logic error there if you look closely. If you put ENABLE=1 and PWM=1 the output of IC1E is leading to a short circuit between your logic supply voltage and GND. This will eventually pull VCC down to a few volts. (could be even the origin of your first problem). Does your arduino not get hot as well?
2. What is the power supply of IC1? 5V? Your lower FETs will like a gate voltage of 10V better than only 5V.
3. Even if you put small resistors at the lower gates, the IC1B/C must source this current. Looking in the datasheet quickly reveals that these chips can only handle a few mA. You will not be able to switch your lower FETs quickly.
4. The basis of Q57 and Q58 only have a connection to the zener diode. See also other answer from Tony EE rocketscientist.

All in all I'd like to advice you to instead use a dedicated MOSFET driver chip. Simple ones are e.g. IR2103 chips. They have most of your functionality on board and you need a handful of components. I think this is better suited also because of the lack of oscilloscope and other measurement equipment.

Comment: I agree that the Cmos Logic ICs have no power supply. The 10106 has an output current that is much too low to quickly charge and discharge the gate capacitance of the N-channel Mosfets.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just a little change above for Pch bias.

Then verify dead-time results with reactive loads for shootthru margin.

Comment: thanks @TonyEErocketscientist , I removed 12v and connected all top parts with +24v line, (please check my updated schematic) , however I don't understand why you connect GND line to power line (+24v)

Comment: That's low ESR Cap (s) 1% of RdsOn +DCR total, right across drivers for small current loop on transients.

Comment: @Hamidsk - That's not a ground connection, it's a capacitor. You want it there to handle load transients when the circuit switches.

Comment: thanks @TonyEErocketscientist for clarification but still understand why you added 2k extra resistor ?!
honestly this sketch  come from last question posted here and answered by Olin-lathrop
-[this question link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395492/pull-push-gate-driver-for-h-bridge-circuit/395623#395623)

Comment: That's a level shifter V/2 to Vcc.  since you made Vcc=12~24V a Zener current limited is ok

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist does this large resistor (2K) has any affect upon turn on/off time of that related Mosfet?

Comment: Emitter follower reduces 2k/hfe to output, so not much

Comment: I see problems with shoot through, where both the upper and lower MOSFETs are on at the same time. The switching thresholds of the MOSFETS are several volts apart. One must be fully off before the other turns on.

Comment: @Gill  perhaps but it depends on BJT latency also depends on Rg Ciss.  1N4148 will surge around 1 Ohm for fast turn off while Rg=10 Ohms for slower turn on to create a differential (Rg-1)Ciss=T  dead time ignoring other influences.  So Rg could be increased to 20 Ohms or so and use PN2222A or better for faster response