# H-bridge MOSFET NAND gate driver suffered from logic voltage drop

Tags: logic-gates, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, nand

I've tried to reproduce the NAND Schmitt triggers circuit to drive my H-bridge MOSFET as per following source:

http://axotron.se/index_en.php?page=34&chapter=0

All my design files are at this GitHub link:

https://github.com/mkeyno/H-bridge2/tree/master/update

It has Enable, PWM and direction pins that are supposed to controlled by Arduino, however my PCB doesn't work yet. I used 74HC132D & CD40106B Schmitt trigger IC and used an LED to indicate each direction, but it never turns on.

Any help is really appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Updated:
I updated new schematic base on new advises , but still has its issue (logic voltage drop)

[image]

Comment: "but it never turn on any help is really appreciated" - you are going to need to be waaaayy more forthcoming with detail if you want help. What have you wired up? PCB? Breadboard? Post photos of your physical circuit. What debugging steps have you tried? Have you checked the power supply? Have you connected the power rails for the NAND gate (you don't show them in your schematic)? Have you probed different parts of the circuit to see what voltages you get?

Comment: @TomCarpenter I did some basic test , such as put different pin in HIGH or LOW mode and check the IC voltage for all IC's but nothings unusual , I've doubted about to selection  of not proper component such as extra resistor or capacitor number , unfortunately I don't have electrical engineering skill or lab tools to trace the error, however I put some PCB image and  all upload all design files for both mosfet and gate driver in the following link    https://github.com/mkeyno/H-bridge2/tree/master/update

Comment: You have the output of your Enable inverter connected to your PWM input. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: @brhans you were right, enable and pwm should not connected, Now I cut enable   and only have 2 line(PWM & Direction) and logic work fine and forward & backward line work as opposite logic , However when not used the Mosfet shield  both forward or backward line shows 5 v , which my high logic level , but when I put it Mosfet shield , voltage on both forward or backward  pin drop to 2 v.   I update the images , kindly check my images or if you could check my schematic of mosfet driver

Comment: @TomCarpenter , can you kindly check new images along with new  problem which arose

Comment: The input impedance to your MOSFET board on the FORWARD and BACKWARD channels isn't much more than around 300 ohms. It's asking a bit too much from the 40106 inverters to drive that much of a load, particularly from a 5V supply. Try disconnecting your LEDs (D1 & D2) and increase the 1k pulldown resistors (R5, R7, R20, etc) to something like maybe 4k7.

Comment: - and I hope C1 isn't really a polarized electrolytic. Either 'forward' or 'backward' will reverse polarize it with unfortunate results...

Comment: @brhans , I did that and I in creased resistors (20,7,5 ,23,13,15) to 3.6K, but as moment to energized board , my mosfets burn out , whats happens ?, what should I do

Comment: R23 or R22 ... ?

Comment: @brhans sorry R22 off course ,(pull down resistor ) also I might add voltage level on FORWARD and BACKWARD slightly increase from 2 to 2.4, but I don't figure out how possibly this little change burn my mosfets! maybe 2.4 put mosfet in conduction load with high Rds  value  and that's burn reason

Comment: @brhans, can you advise me which part is responsible to drop voltage level? I choose the low gate resistor (27 )for mosfets , is it possible that I choose the very low gate resistor?

Comment: If I see right your driving is miswired. Asserting, say forward, will switch on both high and low side MOSFETs of the same leg of the bridge. This is a nice short-circuit across power supply. The same applies to backward and the other two MOSFETs.

Comment: @carloc no it's not , its base on this project 
http://axotron.se/index_en.php?page=34&chapter=0
also my files updated in the following link

https://github.com/mkeyno/H-bridge2/tree/master/update
really appreciated if you could check original file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mosfets in h-bridge get hot on idle load](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395829/mosfets-in-h-bridge-get-hot-on-idle-load)

Comment: @Hamidsk - The files on your [github link](https://github.com/mkeyno/H-bridge2/tree/master/update) are unfortunately useless for anyone who does not have Eagle software installed. You need to use Eagle to produce easily viewable files (e.g. PDF or PNG etc.) for those readers who don't use Eagle or who are viewing this site on a mobile etc. without Eagle installed. Thanks.

Comment: The original design looks okay, drivers are cross connected, left lowside with right highside and vice versa. In your schematics above you don't have this crossing If you set forward you have (forgetting voltage level issues)  left lowside on. And then you have Q6 on, which means Q6 collector low, which copied by follower Q4,Q5 sets left PMOS gates low too and in turn switches them on.

Comment: tnx @carloc, I updated schematic and correct the wiring , but still voltage drop on my nerve,  I read some article  and I may add a Emitter Follower to amplify current  because  I've got no success when I change value of gate or pull down resistor 
I really appreciated if I have you advise for this matter

Comment: @SamGibson I updated PNG file of new schematic , please check

Comment: @Hamidsk - There seems to be a misunderstanding. (a) *None* of the files at your [GitHub link](https://github.com/mkeyno/H-bridge2/tree/master/update) are PNG files. That is my point. So even if you update a PNG file (sometimes) in the question, the GitHub repo can't be used by many readers, as I explained in my previous comment. (b) Also, the [first schematic currently shown in the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0cWU.png) has not been updated to match your updates in comments. You said that you have now "cut enable", yet that signal is still shown as connected on that schematic. Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson  I mean update images here , I will update final design in gitHub

Comment: See also my comments in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/402063/12220. You could also put a discrete push/pull stage at the input of you MOSFET board. This will at least source sufficient current if needed but might lead to other effects. You should start with only one side and also from low to top and take the parts into action piece by piece. So desolder most of the FETs and check the voltage levels. You will eventually find your problem then more likely.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the input impedance of the CD40106B inverters that's the problem, it's the fact that you are totally overloading the outputs. Look at everything you have attached to each one on the MOSFET board:

- Blue LED
- two N-channel MOSFET gates
- bipolar driver for two P-channel MOSFETs

You have 1kΩ pulldowns on the last two items in particular (3 loads), so it's no surprise that the inverter can't drive the control signals high.

The N-channel MOSFETs in particular need to have gate drivers, too, in order to supply the transient current that they need when switching.

Comment: but I picked up advise on comments to increased the pull down resistor  (1k->3.6k) and it increased voltage level (2->2.4) so I though I should go this way to solve the problem(before burn my mosfet ), but I'm bit lost on your comment , can you be more specific or give me troubleshooting procedure

Comment: Look at the output characteristics of the CD40106B. Now look at the input characteristics of all of the loads connected to it. It should be obvious that it can't supply the current required, especially during the switching transient.

Comment: thanks @DaveTweed for reply , but can you advise me how could I solve the problem?,unfortunately I'm not electrical engineering to understand very dip technical term

Comment: Actually, when you're designing circuits at this level, you ARE an electrical engineer, but a rather untrained one.That will come with time, but this project seems to be a bit over your head for now. I think I would recommend that you get a preassembled motor driver board for your Arduino so that you can move ahead with whatever it is you're trying to accomplish, and then come back to these issues at a later time. Start by studying how the commercial board works.

Comment: thanks @DaveTweed for your advise but I'd rather to keep my searching to find proper solution for this project in this forum

Comment: I increase all pull down resistor to 10k and made separate emitter follower circuit for both LED and 'forward' - 'backward' command pin
please check